# How to print full path of a file being sourced?

Tags: tcl

let say there is a file a/b/c/d.tcl and it should print its full path when being sourced.

```
source d.tcl
```

And the output should be

```
a/b/c/d.tcl
```

How to do this? Is there any tcl variable which stores the full path info of the file being sourced?

Answer (score 1):

The `info script` command returns the file that is currently evaluated. Combine that with `file normalize` to get the full path:

```
puts [file normalize [info script]]
```

Beware that `info script` is only valid while the file is evaluated. Calling `info script` from procs that are defined by the script, but are evaluated later in response to an event will not produce the name of the file that defined the proc.

You sometimes see the claim that `info script` cannot be used in a proc. That is incorrect. It can be used in a proc, but it only produces a useful result if that proc is called directly while evaluating the script.

Example:

```
proc foo {} {
    puts [file normalize [info script]]
}

# This works fine:
foo

# This should not be trusted to produce the expected result:
after 5000 foo
```

To make that last command work, you would have to store the result of `info script` in a variable, and use that in your proc.

Comment: I like to put `variable scriptName [file normalize [info script]]` in my source files.